# Macro VBA para Exel - copiar dados de uma folha para outra com uma condição

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, microsoft-office

Viva pessoal, 
Sou completamente novato em VBA e pricipiante em programação. 
Preciso de ajuda para construir uma macro para Excel.

**Contexto:**
No livro Excel que se encontra no link a seguir,  pretendo desenvolver uma macro em VBA que preencha os campos “transatas", "finalizadas" e "aguardar" da folha “Relatorio”, com a informação contida nos campos “num transatas", "num finalizadas" e "num aguardar" da folha “Dia18Set”.

**Problema:** 
A informação do “Dia18Set” é produzida periodicamente de forma completamente aleatória. Cada vez que a folha é produzida, os "códigos do processo" não são sempre os mesmos, nem aparecem pela mesma ordem.

Logo, na macro tenho que verificar, primeiramente, se existe o "Código do processo” que pretendo preencher na folha “Relatorio”.

Se o “código do processo”  da folha “Relatorio” não existir na folha “Dia18Set” não preenche nada.

Se existir, a rotina terá que buscar os valores " num transatas", "num finalizadas" e " num aguardar" presentes na folha “Dia18Set”e preencher automaticamente os respetivos campos da folha “Relatorio”.

Em anexo, segue o ficheiro Excel e o ficheiro com o código que desenvolvi, mas não está a funcionar.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Link ficheiro Excel -> https://www.sendspace.com/file/m2tvbb

Código desenvolvido

```
Sub transferirDados()
Dim tarefasRecebidas As Long
Dim tarefasProcessadas As Long
Dim tarefasPendentes As Long

Dim IdProcesso As String

Dim ultimaLinhaDia18Set As Long
Dim ultimalinhaRelatorio As Long

Dim contLinhasDia18Set As Long
Dim contLinhasRelatorio As Long

 'Definir numero total de linhas da folha "Relatorio"
ultimalinhaRelatorio = Sheets("Relatorio").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Definir numero total de linhas da folha "Dia18Set"
ultimaLinhaDia18Set = Sheets("Dia18Set").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



' O "primeiro For" itera cada umas das linhas da folha "Relatorio" a partir da linha 3 para obter cada um dos "IdProcesso"
For contLinhasRelatorio = 3 To ultimalinhaRelatorio

    IdProcesso = Sheets("Relatorio").Cells(contLinhasRelatorio, 1)

' O segundo For itera cada uma das linhas da folha "Dia18Set" a partir da linha 2, para obter cada um dos "IdProcesso"
    For contLinhasDia18Set = 2 To ultimaLinhaDia18Set

        ' Para cada linha da folha "Dia18Set", verifica se o "Id do processo" da folha "Dia18Set" é igual ao "Id do processo" que esté em análise no "primeiro For"
        If Sheets("Dia18Set").Cells(contLinhasDia18Set, 1) Like IdProcesso Then

        'Caso o "IDprocesso" da folha "Dia18Set" seja igual ao da folha "Relatorio", atribui o valor da respetiva linha e coluna às variáves "tarefasRecebidas","tarefasProcessadas" e "tarefasPendentes"
            tarefasRecebidas = Sheets("Dia18Set").Cells(contLinhasDia18Set, 2)
            tarefasProcessadas = Sheets("Dia18Set").Cells(contLinhasDia18Set, 3)
            tarefasPendentes = Sheets("Dia18Set").Cells(contLinhasDia18Set, 4)

            'Atribui à célula do livro "Relatorio" o numero das respetivas tarefas.
            Sheets("Relatorio").Cells(contLinhasRelatorio, 2) = tarefasRecebidas
            Sheets("Relatorio").Cells(contLinhasRelatorio, 3) = tarefasProcessadas
            Sheets("Relatorio").Cells(contLinhasRelatorio, 4) = tarefasPendentes
        End If
    Next contLinhasDia18Set
Next contLinhasRelatorio
End Sub
```

Comment: Favor [inserir seu código com a formatação correta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e não por imagens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o IDprocesso precisa ser exatamente igual, você não utiliza o [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/like-operator), pois o mesmo normalmente é utilizado para obter matches parciais com wildcards. Portanto, `If Sheets("Dia18Set").Cells(contLinhasDia18Set, 1) Like IdProcesso Then` pode ser alterado para:

```
If Sheets("Dia18Set").Cells(contLinhasDia18Set, 1) = IdProcesso Then
```

Obs.:Este código funcionou para mim com `Like` ou `=`

Em que a Planilha Dia18Set:

```
+---+--------+-------+---+----+
|   |   A    |   B   | C | D  |
+---+--------+-------+---+----+
| 2 | cod_3  | 10000 | 1 |  4 |
| 3 | cod_4  |  9000 | 2 |  5 |
| 4 | cod_5  |  8000 | 3 |  6 |
| 5 | cod_1  |  7000 | 4 |  7 |
| 6 | cod_7  |  6000 | 5 |  8 |
| 7 | cod_8  |  5000 | 6 |  9 |
| 8 | cod_9  |  4000 | 7 | 10 |
| 9 | cod_10 |  3000 | 8 | 11 |
+---+--------+-------+---+----+
```

Produziu este resultado:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
|    |        A        |     B     |      C      |    D     |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |                 | 18/set    |             |          |
|  2 | Código Processo | transatas | finalizadas | aguardar |
|  3 | cod_1           | 7000      | 4           | 7        |
|  4 | cod_2           |           |             |          |
|  5 | cod_3           | 10000     | 1           | 4        |
|  6 | cod_4           | 9000      | 2           | 5        |
|  7 | cod_5           | 8000      | 3           | 6        |
|  8 | cod_6           |           |             |          |
|  9 | cod_7           | 6000      | 5           | 8        |
| 10 | cod_8           | 5000      | 6           | 9        |
| 11 | cod_9           | 4000      | 7           | 10       |
| 12 | cod_10          | 3000      | 8           | 11       |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

> Na próxima vez, tente enviar exemplos das suas tabelas pelo [ASCII
>   Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

.

Comment: Agradeço a atenção. A alteração funcionou.  A primeira parte do problema está resolvida. Também terei em atenção a questão dos exemplos da tabela. Muito Obrigado